How to address requests for Bitcoin book overviews?
I noticed that we have multiple questions that collect bitcoin book recommendations per answer post. So far I have found:

What are some good resources for understanding Bitcoin?
Any books about Bitcoin?
Is there a reference, authoritative resource or book on Bitcoin programming?
Blockchain programming books C#?
Where can I find resources for programmers to understand Bitcoin?
General book recommendation
cryptography book or resource
A "Bitcoin for dummies" guide?
Is there developer documentation for the Bitcoin Core source code?

These sort of questions are generally a bad fit for the stack exchange work flow: later answers are inherently disadvantaged in score, the big number of posts makes it hard to get an overview, duplicates need to be curated, the answer quality tends to be all over the place, there is no clear “best, complete answer”, and other issues.
I'm curious to hear ideas how we should approach the situation (e.g. close the “shopping list” topics, merge all of them, leave everything as is, …).

I propose that we convert one of these topics to a canonical-question with a community wiki answer, and collect the answers from most of the above questions into a table overview similar to the answer on “The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List” on Stack Overflow. Excerpt below:

If there is support for my proposal, we could discuss in another topic the categories and which of the listed (and maybe additional) topics should be collected.

+1. I can already think of some categories, and also of some non-categories like "blockchain programming" (lol) or "cryptography" (which has its own SE site).
